# proof of integral diverging

Tags: calculus, integration

So the idea behind this proof is to use limits of definite integrals.

Question: If

0$\lt$b $\leqslant$1, then $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^b}dx$$ diverges.

I was wondering how might this proof be done? What does it mean by using th elimits of the definite integral.

Comment: Compare to $\int_{1}^{t} \frac{1}{x}$, which is $\log(t)$.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that by definition

$$\int_1^\infty {1\over x}dx = \lim_{a\to\infty} \int_1^a {1\over x}dx$$

and

- $0<b<1 \implies\int \frac{1}{x^b}dx=\frac{x^{1-b}}{1-b}+c$
- $b=1 \implies\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln x+c$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{M\to +\infty} \int_1^M \frac{1}{x^b}\ dx = \frac{x^{1-b}}{1-b}\bigg|_1^M = \frac{M^{1-b}}{1-b}$$

You can easily see that as $M\to +\infty$ the integral does diverge, unless $1-b < 0$ that is, $b>1$ (which is not your case).